# Can a output stream, in C, which is full buffered, be flushed automatically even before the buffer is fully filled?

Tags: c, buffer

Consider this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char buffer[500];
    int n = setvbuf(stdout, buffer, _IOFBF, 100);
    
    printf("Hello");
    while(1 == 1)
        ;
    return 0;
}
```

When run on Linux, the "Hello" message appears on the output device immediately, and the program then hangs indefinitely.  Shouldn't the output instead be buffered until `stdout` is flushed or closed, either manually or at normal program termination?  That's what seems to happen on Windows 10, and also what happens on Linux if the buffer size is specified as 130 bytes or more.  I am using VS Code on both systems.

What am I missing? Am I wrong about the Full Buffering Concept?

Comment: This usage is illegal: the buffer lives in automatic storage ("the stack") , and after return from main, the final flush would reference it. [ the same code is used as an example of invalid usage in `man setvbuf`  ]

Comment: To be clear, @wildplasser, the `setvbuf` call itself is not illegal, and, considered in isolation, its behavior is well defined.  It would be fine if the affected stream were closed before the end of the buffer's lifetime.  But as you observe, the example code does not do that.

Comment: Do compare apples to apples.  You describe testing a modified version of the program on Windows, one that goes into an infinite loop instead of `sleep()`ing.  Have you tried that version on Linux?

Comment: Yes sir, i have tried it. It prints the string "Hello" on linux with the infinite loop.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Well, he does not close it, or unbuffer it, so the flush+close by the runtime will reference the (by then) illegal buffer.

Comment: It seems like reasonable behavior.  Certainly the C language allows this, and I doubt that any other standard would forbid it.

Comment: Then `sleep()` and `unistd.h` are irrelevant to the question, @ShahFahad. The implied suggestion was that in that event you should edit the question to remove mention of them.  I have helped you out with that.

Comment: That would be exactly the question, I think, @WilliamPursell.  *Does* the standard allow output to a fully-buffered stream to be delivered to the device before the buffer is filled or the stream is flushed or closed?  (I'm inclined to agree that it does, but that's not self-evident.)  And secondarily, why is that affected by the buffer size?

Comment: Declar `static char buffer[500];` since `stdout` exists when `main` returns

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch : that is what I commented 22 hours ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What am I missing? Am I wrong about the Full Buffering Concept?

You are not wrong about the concept. There is wiggle room in the wording of the language of the specification, as @WilliamPursell observes in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66197163/2402272), but  your program's observed behavior does not exhibit full buffering according to the express intent of the specification.  Moreover, I interpret the specification as leaving room here for implementations to conform despite being incapable for one reason or another of implementing the intent, not as offering a free pass for implementations that reasonably can implement the intent nevertheless to do something different at will.

I tested this variation on your program against Glibc 2.22 on Linux:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    static char buffer[BUFSIZ] = { 0 };
    int n = setvbuf(stdout, buffer, _IOFBF, 100);

    if (n != 0) {
        perror("setvbuf");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Hello");
    puts(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

The program exited with status 0 and did not print any error output, so I conclude that `setvbuf` returned 0, indicating success.  However, the program printed "Hello" only once, showing that in fact it did not use the specified buffer.  If I increase the buffer size specified to `setvbuf` to 128 bytes (== 2<sup>7</sup>) then the output is "HelloHello", showing that the specified buffer is used.

The observed behavior, then, seems to be<sup>1</sup> that this implementation of `setvbuf` silently sets the stream to *un*buffered when the provided buffer is specified to be smaller than 128 bytes.  That is consistent with the behavior of your version of the program, too, but inconsistent with my reading of the function's specifications:

> [...]The argument `mode` determines how `stream` will be buffered, as
> follows: `_IOFBF` causes input/output to be fully buffered [...]. If
> `buf` is not a null pointer, the array it points to may be used instead
> of a buffer allocated by the `setvbuf` function and the argument
> `size` specifies the size of the array; otherwise, `size` may
> determine the size of a buffer allocated by the `setvbuf` function.
> The contents of the array at any time are indeterminate.
>
> The `setvbuf` function returns zero on success, or nonzero if an
> invalid value is given for `mode` or if the request cannot be honored.

([C17](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf), 7.21.5.6/2-3)

As I read the specification, `setvbuf` is free to use the specified buffer or not, at its discretion, and if it chooses not to do so then it may or may not use a buffer of the specified size, but it must either set the specified buffering mode or fail.  It is inconsistent with those specifications for it to change the buffering mode to one that is different from both the original mode and the requested mode, and it is also inconsistent to fail to set the requested mode and nevertheless return 0.

Inasmuch as I conclude that this Glibc version's `setvbuf` is behaving contrary to the language specification, I'd say you've tripped over a glibc bug.

---

<sup>1</sup> But it should be noted that the specifications say that the contents of the buffer at any time are indeterminate.  Therefore, by accessing the buffer after asking `setvbuf` to assign it as a stream buffer, this program invokes undefined behavior, hence, technically, it does not prove anything.

Comment: `char buffer[BUFSIZ] = { 0 };` Please change to static to avoid UB: `static char buffer[BUFSIZ] = { 0 };` If the program exits with code=0, it is merely coincidence.

Comment: Fine, @wildplasser, but as the answer observes, the code has UB quite apart from that.  It is meant as documentation of an experiment, not as a model to emulate.

Answer (score 0):

Given the lack of specificity in the standard, I would argue that such behavior is not prohibited.

According to https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_05:

When a stream is "unbuffered", bytes are intended to appear from the source or at the destination as soon as possible; otherwise, bytes may be accumulated and transmitted as a block. When a stream is "fully buffered", bytes are intended to be transmitted as a block when a buffer is filled. When a stream is "line buffered", bytes are intended to be transmitted as a block when a  byte is encountered. Furthermore, bytes are intended to be transmitted as a block when a buffer is filled, when input is requested on an unbuffered stream, or when input is requested on a line-buffered stream that requires the transmission of bytes. Support for these characteristics is implementation-defined, and may be affected via setbuf() and setvbuf().

Comment: Somewhat contrary to my comment on the question, although I agree that buffering behavior is largely at implementation discretion, I don't think that's a sufficient explanation for what's going one here.